# Rmagick image in special area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, transparency, rmagick

I have an image in which I would put another image.
My image is a kind of cloud and I would to insert an other image in white area (inside of the cloud).
The outside of the image is transparent and I need of this transparency.

My image is in '.png' format.

Do you have any idea to how to do it?

Comment: Have you read the docs and tried anything yet?

Comment: http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/usage.html